# Save As CSV Results Differently With VBA and Dialogue Box

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-csv, save-as

I am trying to export an excel file as csv. However I do not want a comma seperated file.

When I use Save As dialogue box to save the file as .csv I have what I want as follows;

[image]

When I do the same procedure with record macro I have the following code;

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\...path...\Kitap20.csv", _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close
```

Since I want date record in the file name I do the following changes in the code (which works fine for the file name part);

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strDesktopPath & "\my_file_" & DateF & 
".csv", _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

Since I do not touch file format settings in the code, I expect to have the same output file, however, it creates a comma seperated file as follows;

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Best Regards,

Comment: What do the two files look like if you just open them in a text editor, like notepad or textpad?

Comment: Hi Josh; vba file gives Name,Surname,Age and dialogue box file gives Name;Surname;Age when I open them with Notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strDesktopPath & "\my_file_" & DateF & 
".csv", _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
```